# Animation-Copy And Paste Pose

Tags: animation

I've been trying to copy and paste a pose from the character's right arm (Suffix: .R) and left arm (Suffix: .L) I copy the pose from the right arm (This is a walking animation) and paste it reversed (Shift Command V) But then this happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rPlj.png
 I don't know what to do, and if you guys want the .blend file, go to 
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52230

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem of bones orientation, in *Edit* mode select your left upper and lower arms and rotate them (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) 180° and it should work.

Comment: Omg! Thank you so much, I've been getting so frustrated. Im only 12 and I've been blending since I was 10, and I never came across that problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Wow if you are only 12 you gonna be the master of 3d!!!

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate that!

Comment: Ill try and send the final video. I kind of need some feedback.